# Reload Linux Desktop without reboot or logging off and re-logging back in?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, gnome

Is there a terminal command that can

```
reload the desktop
```

in centos linux desktop for example ?

i would like to reload the desktop so everything gets refreshed.

because currently some deleted files are not disappearing like they are suppose to
and some new files are not appearing like they are suppose to.

Comment: There may be a key that refreshes the window, (*e.g.*, Windows has one, `F5`). If you're using Gnome, it's `Ctrl-R` I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LMDE (linux mint debian edition) `F5` refreshes the desktop, but this question probably belongs in unix.stackexchange.com